# How to code the radio buttons below paragraph to animate images on the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am producing the page shown in the attached screen shot. The page has 2 div sections (left & right section) nested within a main container div. I have used the following HTML:

```
<div class="places" id="places">
  <img src="images/places-img.png" alt="places" />
  <div class ="placetext">
    <h2>Places</h2> 
    <p>Experience Japan...</p>
  </div>
</div
```

I have also used the following CSS:

```
.places {
background-color: #000000;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;}

.places img {
float: right;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;}

.placetext {
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;}`

.placetext h2 {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-top: 30%;
color: white; 
font-family: Electroharmonix;
padding-left: 15%;
border-bottom: 5px solid #DC1A31;}

.placetext p {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", "serif";
font-weight: 200;
text-align: justify;
font-size: 16px;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 30px;
column-rule: 1px solid white;
margin: 0 8%;
line-height: 1.8;}
```

I want to know how to include those radio buttons below the text and link them to the image on the right, so when the buttons are clicked on they allow the image on the right to slow-transition by pushing left smoothly to the next image like a carousel.

on the right side, I intend to include 5 images.

I don't know much about JavaScript but I know this may require it to animate the images.

**Edit:

I did this off a gallery earlier but it completely ruins the layout no matter how much I tinker with it- Javascript:

```
    <script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9MRT.jpg)

Comment: Where is the javascript you tried?  There are many image galleries out there that you can "borrow" code from to get this working.  Make a concerted effort and show us what you tried and failed with and then you will probably get some help.  Most people on StackOverflow are not willing to write your code for you.

Comment: Heres my Javascript:

Comment: good, now make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You can use dummy images from dummyimage.com any size you want [like this](https://dummyimage.com/400x300)

Comment: I was simply trying to help you get help here on StackOverflow. I’ve been using this site for many years both for my own needs and to help others. I was new once also and got shot down many times for poor questions that don’t conform to StackOverflow “rules”, so now I spend a good portion of time guiding new users in a direction that will get them answers if I can’t answer myself. You were kind of looking for a free ride before posting the JavaScript. I don’t doubt that you spent  a lot of time on this. Next time format your question better and hopefully with a better attitude you’ll be helped